# When the compiler is free to terminate a loop?

Tags: c

```
6.8.5.6 
An iteration statement whose controlling expression is not a constant expression,
that performs no input/output operations, does not access volatile objects, and 
performs no synchronization or atomic operations in its body, controlling 
expression, or (in the case of a for statement) its expression-3, may be assumed 
by the implementation to terminate.
```

Compiler is ready to terminate a loop if the above condition is met. Is that true?
If yes, I was trying to simulate a scenario of this kind but no success.
I tried,

```
int main()
{
    // Some statements...
    {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 100;
        int i=0;
        while(++i>=0)
        {
            a = b;
        }
    }
    // Some statements...
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help me to simulate this scenario.

Thanks,

Comment: I am using VS 2010, do i need to turn on optimization or do some configuration changes to simulate this scenario?

Comment: No, you'd need a proper C compiler. VS2010 is not.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the compiler can assume anything there. Integer overflow is Undefined Behavior. If you'd written `while (i==0)` 6.8.5.6  would apply.

Answer (score 0):

Try with compiler optimization levels like **-O2, -O3**. It should help you :)

Note:

For GCC family of  compilers try **-O2 or -O3**

For MSVC try **/O2 or /O3**